# How can I add a any string option to a typescript literal string enum?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to allow any arbitrary string value on a literal string type and allow for intellisense. Consider the following type:

`type possibleValues = 'value0' | 'value1' | 'value2'`

This in vscode will show

[image]

But if i change my code to:

`type possibleValues = 'value0' | 'value1' | 'value2' | string`

I no longer get intellisense, but the code will work as expected.

My question is, is there a way to set this type so that it will allow for an arbitrary string value while offering intellisense?

Comment: `"foo" | string` type gets widened to its super type `string`, so you will lose the string literal. Would be interesting to see, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am writing a lib for an api, which has some default endpoints like 'default', 'bug' etc, but it does allow one to add custom endpoints. I am trying to preserve intellisense for the default values while being able to add custom endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Im unsure if this works for variable declaration. But for `Functions` and `classes` the following approch can be used:

```
function f(a: "value1" | "value2")
function f(a: string)
function f(a: string) {

}
```

The first overload will be considered first (providing auto completion). If it doesnt match any more, the second one is beeing consulted.

Comment: This is a great answer @zzrv, but yes, overloading functions isnt my issue here. Its the variable declaration that is the issue.